# Moving at higher speed than normal in geometry dash

Tags: geometry-dash

I have a level in geometry dash that always ran at a consistent speed when I playtested it. But randomly, it started to be out of sync with the song, and when at 3x or 4x speeds went faster than it should have. This correlates with smooth fix, as when smooth fix was on it would go faster. But that makes no sense as smooth fix is meant to slow the game. Its pretty inconsistent, as sometimes it goes at ~1.5x speed over normal while other times it is barely faster. I thought this had something to do with noclip, but the issue was still there with or without noclip.
Has anyone else encountered this bug, and does anyone know a fix?

Comment: This sounds to me like the intended framerate of the game is being sped up for some reason. You might have an FPS bypass tool enabled?